# Copying cells values from a changing source into another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

This is a bit similar to previous questions I've asked, but I haven't figured out the trick to this problem. I currently have two worksheets, on the first I have sets of two columns which have a few hundred rows beneath them. I have it set up such that the user can add more sets of these columns as needed, and formulas/formats are transferred as needed. There can be any number of these sets of columns, though they will always start in Column "D" and the final set will always be 10 columns before the last column of the worksheet.

Now I'm looking at bringing over the headers for these new columns (which are always in row 2) to another worksheet. Additionally, I'm bringing over the values found in 4 rows of each of these sets of columns (all of which are merged) so that's another four values per set of two columns. The idea behind the code below is that I take the header value at the top, look for the row that has it in one column of another worksheet, and add it if it's not found. Then it should use the row number where it was found/added and set the cells to the right (4 columns) equal to the other four values mentioned previously.

I constructed a while loop to do this, and my thought process was that it would do this for one column set (starting at say D2), and then go to F2, and so on.

```
With ws1
    lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With 

StopColumn = lastColumn - 10

' I'm trying to find the last set of columns here, no matter how many the user adds the final one will be 10 before the sheet's final column


i = 4
While i <= StopColumn
    ColumnName = ws1.Cells(2, i).Value
' I'm trying to grab the header here, it's a merged cell for both of the columns
    With ws2
        With .Range("C7", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
            Set foundRng = .Find(what:=ColumnName, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
            If foundRng Is Nothing And WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells) > 0 Then Set foundRng = .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks)
            If foundRng Is Nothing Then Set foundRng = .Cells(.Count + 1)
        End With
    End With
    ' Trying to see if they already have that header name in the new worksheet, and if not I'm adding it to column C of the first blank row
    With foundRng
        .Value = ColumnName
        .Cells(7, 3).Resize(, 7).Value = Array(ws1.Cells(3, i).Value, _
        ws1.Cells(22, i).Value, _
        ws1.Cells(108, i).Value, _
        ws1.Cells(122, i).Value)
    End With
    ' Bringing over the cell values to the columns of the new row on the other worksheet
    ColumnName = ""
    i = i + 2
    ' I'm counting +2 to move to the next set of merged cells
Wend
```

I believe I may be overthinking the solution to this problem, I would appreciate any help with getting this to a working state. I think I could use the offset function to make the stopcolumn part of my code a bit more efficient, but past that I'm not sure.

Comment: Currently the macro works, but things are not going over to the other worksheet correctly. The 'names' (row 2, column i) are populating properly on the other worksheet. However, the values are being populated 1 column over and 6 columns down, rather than directly to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what I was doing wrong -

```
.Cells(7, 3).Resize(, 7).Value
```

Should have instead read

```
.Cells(7, 2).Resize(, 4).Value
```

I forgot that due to the way I structured 'foundRng' that the resize would work from that as a starting point, meaning that the original code was moving things down 7 downs/over 1 additional column than needed.